# HTML.DropDownList not showing the selected value

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

Please a really need some help. I getting crazy with this one.

I'm trying to build in a page 7 Tab's with 2 DropDown's in for selecting value. The list his always the same but in each tab i have a different selected value.

Everything goes well with the first one but i can't make the second one work.

Her is my Razor code:

```
 @Html.DropDownList("Q21_objectivos", new SelectList
    (Model.Q21_ObjectivosList, "Value", "Text", Model.Q21_Objs[i - 1]),
    "Seleccione um objectivo",
    new
    {
     id = "objectivo" + i.ToString(),
     @class = "form-control",
     @onchange = "detectarObjectivoDuplicado( " + i + ", $(this).val() );"
    })
```

This one is not working:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Q21_AvaliacaoLista",
new SelectList(Model.Q21_AvaliacaoLista, "Value", "Text",    Model.Q21_Pontuacao[i - 1]), 
new 
{
 id = "avalObjectivo" + i.ToString(),
 @class = "form-control",
 @onchange = "CalculaPontRes();"
})
```

Here is the resulting HTML:

```
<select class="form-control" id="objectivo1" name="Q21_objectivos" onchange="detectarObjectivoDuplicado( 1, $(this).val() );"><option value="">Seleccione um objectivo</option>
<option selected="selected" value="1">Preencher as tarefas em DotProject até ao dia 1 do mês seguinte</option>
<option value="2">Desenvolver aplicação SIADAP3</option>
<option value="3">Resolver 70% dos tickets atribuidos</option>
<option value="4">Desenvolver 2 aplicações locais em VB.net</option>
<option value="5">Desenvolver 2 aplicações locais em COBOL</option>
</select>
```

The resulting HTML of the not selecting dropdownlist:

```
<select class="form-control" id="avalObjectivo1" name="Q21_AvaliacaoLista" onchange="CalculaPontRes();"><option value="5">Superado (Pontuação 5)</option>
<option value="3">Atingido (Pontuação 3)</option>
<option value="1">Não Atingido (Pontuação 1)</option>
<option value="0">Avalie o Objectivo</option>
</select>
```

What can I say more... The model is loaded with the list as it's possible to see in the resulting HTML.

Comment: for 2nd one its setting selected value for options. have you setting this value..on load or while 2nd tab click through javascript

Comment: What is not working with the second one? What is the expected result?

Comment: The second one is not setting the selected value. It only loads the DropDownList but Model.Q21_Pontuacao[i - 1] (where the selected value is) it's not working. The selected one is always the first one in the list.

Answer (score 1):

If you change the property name "Q21_AvaliacaoLista" to something else, the selectedvalue will work.

The property name (Q21_AvaliacaoLista) and the list of items (Model.Q21_AvaliacaoLista) cannot have the same name.

Maybe it is because of data biding of MVC...

Answer (score 0):

I just made it work by changing **"Q21_AvaliacaoLista"** to **"Q21_Avaliacao"** in the DropDownList that wasn't working.

Somehow the name was making probably a conflict. I don't understand why but this way it's working.

Comment: Yes, This is one of the many (but a common) reasons why people have problems with using DropDownList rather than DropDownListFor.  The HTML helper is very tightly coupled with the ViewData dictionary, and it gets confused when your list of items has the same name as the selected item name.  Always use different names for your list and selected item.

Comment: I've tried DropDownListFor but I had the same problem because of this: @DropDownListFor(m => m.Q21_AvaliacaoLista <--- Resulting in the same name problem and also this way I only get the selected value if it was passed in Q21_AvaliacaoLista.. making Model.Q21_Pontuacao[i - 1] not useful and I would end up with the same thing in the 7 TAB's i was building. (Hope i'm not being to confuse).